# Excel complicated array

Tags: arrays, excel

I have a very long formula that churns out the correct answer when it is just focussed on calculating one row.

I want to turn this into an array that will sum over multiple rows, however as soon as i turn the formula into an array it then gives an incorrect value... and i don't know why! For some reason it seems to do an extra multiplication when i put it into an array, i believe anyway.

Original working formula on single row:
=(IFERROR(.........

+12.5*$C15), ....)

Not working array:
{=SUM(IFERROR(.........

+12.5*$C15:$C16), ....)

When C15 is 0.5, the array returns a value that is 6.25 too low
When C15 is 1, the array returns a value that is 12.5 too low
When C15 is 1, the array returns a value that is 25 too low

So it is most definitely something to do with the 12.5 but i don't understand why turning it into an array makes it return a value too low.

Comment: Definitely it has something to do with the `...`.

Comment: Asking for help with a formula and then not providing the full formula is not an ideal request.

Comment: After looking further into the problem - as soon as i turn the formula into an array it disregards the final "+12.5*$C15:$C16" and it is not included in the calculation hence why it is too low ?

Comment: I didn't provide the formula as the part i have filled with .... has nothing to do with the calculation and would just confuse the matter.

Comment: Without providing the rest of the formula or the expected results (You say the results are different to your objective but not the objective) then the extent of help you can receive is that your formula is resolving as sum(x+(12.5*C15),x+(12.5*C16))

Answer (score 1):

Based on the duplicate question found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42025870/excel-array-formula-complicated?noredirect=1

You do not need the IFERROR:

The CSE array formula:

```
 =SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("S",B2:B3,1), 1, 2))
```

Remove the quotes around the numbers, with quotes they are strings and SUM will ignore them.

The ISNUMBER takes the place of the IFERROR.

This is **an array formula** and needs to be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.  
If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.